# HTML5 localStorage Showing Different Data in Different Frames (Same Domain)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage

I am seeing an issue that, by my reading, shouldn't be happening.  In short, I have a web application with nested iframes. The frame containership is as shown below:

```
http://mysite.doh
    https://othersite.duh
        https://mysite.doh/Panel.html?urlparam1=x
    https://mysite.doh/Panel.html?urlparam2=y
```

Note: I have been careful about indicating the http vs. https, since protocol is part of what is considered for the same origin policy. These are indeed HTTPS iframes inside of an HTTP main page.  When the Panel.html opens, it attempts to record a couple of query parameters so that its twin panel(s) also knows them.  So there is code like:

```
urlparam1 = $.urlParam('urlparam1 ');
if (urlparam1 == null || urlparam1 == ''){
    urlparam1  = localStorage.getItem("urlparam1");
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("urlparam1", urlparam1);
}
```

My goal is to transfer the value of urlparam1 to all versions of Panel.html.  This is actually the case any time a panel opens on the browser, and each version of the Panel has a polling function to look for changed data in the localStorage.

However, localStorage seems to not be getting the job done correctly. Changes to localStorage on one panel are not reflected in its counterpart. This seems mighty odd, since it is my understanding that localStorage is to be shared by all pages with the same origin.  The two panels are definitely the same origin: they're literally the same URL, just with different query parameters.

Anyone know why this might be the case?  I have looked at the localStorage dictionaries, and they have completely different data inside of them (e.g., one has urlparam1, the other urlparam2- they should both have the same data, with both values available). I can think of no reason why this might be the case. The origins are identical (including the protocol). The browsers I have been testing with are FireFox and Chrome (mostly FireFox).

**EDIT:** As an update, it seems like it might be due to the settings for the iframe built by otherside.duh.  They are allowing scripts, but may be disallowing `allow-same-origin`. (Source: https://readable-email.org/list/whatwg/topic/cross-origin-iframe-and-sandbox-allow-same-origin)  This appears to be advised on many older sites, since it indicates that if both `allow scripts` and `allow-same-origin` are enabled, the iframe can then remove its own `sandbox` property.  Is that still true (sources were 2013)?  Because that sounds like an incredibly bad design decision, if so. I can't imagine why anyone would want that to be desired behavior.  To clarify what `allow-same-origin` does, it is

> If you don't have allow-same-origin, the content ends up in a unique origin, not its "real" origin.

So it's as if your frame runs on some arbitrary site, rather than the one that you actually use.

Comment: Are you using always the param via query string? Or just the the second domain init the param from localStorage?

Comment: Both of the links have query parameters, which are not necessarily the same.  The intention of this code is to be able to synchronize certain panel values that are initially set on one panel, but not the other.

Comment: You need to use storage events.

Comment: Which storage events are necessary in this case? It was my understanding that the localStorage was a shared object, which should immediately change for all entities accessing it once it has changed.  Is that not the case?